# JQuery trigger event when page loads

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a dropdown list and I want the first element of the list to trigger event automatically when the page loads.

My jquery current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".size").change(function() {
        var searchbox = $(this).val();
        var myId = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'searchword=' + searchbox + '&product_id=' + myId;
        if (searchbox == '') {} else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "check_stock.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#display" + myId).html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});​
</script>
```

html code

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">
    <label>Size:</label>
    <select name="size" class="size" id="'.$pid.'">

    <option value="XS">XS</option>
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="XL">XL</option>
    <option value="XXL">XXL</option>
    <option value="3XL">3XL*</option>
    <option value="4XL">4XL*</option>
    <option value="5XL">5XL*</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" class="pid" value="'.$pid.'" />
    <span id="display'.$pid.'"></span>
    </form>
```

Currently it only trigger when you select something from the dropdown list.
(Any help appreciated.)

Comment: Are you sure you really want to do an AJAX stock-check call for Extra Small (XS) whenever the page loads?  How about making the first option: `Please select`, ensuring the onchange is called if/when the user actually chooses their size?

Comment: or generating the page with php the way it's supposed to look like after the call. `<span id="display'.$pid.'"><?php echo '...' ?></span>`

Answer (score 3):

try adding this line after you add the listener:

```
$(".size").change();
```

this should fire your event on the dropdown list just as if someone selected an option.

Comment: This is how it work at the moment
http://www.mysandbow.webatu.com/view_product?product=1

Comment: The client wants  the add to cart to show up when the page load, because she think people won't buy anything if they don't see add to cart button.

Comment: @Raphael1 :) you are following that tutorial from the book? (what was the name...)

Comment: lol am following a tutorial but it not from a book, am following this
http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/autosuggestion-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html

Comment: lol fixed it by adding this <span id="display'.$pid.'"><input type="submit" name="button" class="btn" value="Add to  Cart" /></span>